# Mocking view helpers with rspec-rails 2.0.0.beta.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to mock a view helper with rspec2. The old way of doing this throws an error, complaining the template object is not defined:

```
template.should_receive(:current_user).and_return(mock("user"))
```

Am I missing something here, or is this not implemented in rspec2 (yet)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out meself:

```
view.should_receive(:current_user).and_return(mock("user"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it documented anywhere? I just looked up this very thing earlier today and got the `template` answer.